# Automatização do código

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, db2, oracle18c

Utilizando um banco de dados DB2

Preciso automatizar uma query e atualmente tenho o seguinte cenário:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE DATA1 < '2020-06-01' AND DATA2 >= '2020-05-01'
```

Como fazer para que as condições de data sempre sejam:

DATA1 = o primeiro dia do mês seguinte

DATA2 = o primeiro dia do mês atual

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade é usar a função `date_trunc('month', now())` para obter o início do mês atual e `add_months(date_trunc('month', now()), 1)` para obter o início do mês seguinte.